# Is there an 'Informatica Powercenter' free/evaluation version available?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Is there an "Informatica Powercenter" free/evaluation version available ?
I am asking in context of learning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is the free express version. Go to: https://community.informatica.com/solutions/pcexpress. This is a piece of the complete package, and has the Developers package in small. Also contains a tutorial.

Comment: Remember that _PowerCenter_ is an ambiguous name - there is _PowerCenter Designer_ (older, more established) and _PowerCenter Developer_ (newer, less stable, less feature-complete). PC Express is the latter.